# How do I append variables to a dataframe coming from a function passed in a Python loop?

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to have this output:

```
campaign | mean | left | right 
A        | 5%   | 0%   | 10% 
B        | 8%   | 2%   | 6% etc.
```

Right now, I am using a python function within a loop to get the 4 variables:
campaign, mean, left, right. Here is the function:

```
import numpy as np
def bootstrap_ci(df, variable, classes, repetitions = 1000, alpha = 0.05, random_state=None):df = df[[variable, classes]]bootstrap_sample_size = len(df)

mean_diffs = []

for i in range(repetitions):
    bootstrap_sample = df.sample(n = bootstrap_sample_size, replace = True, random_state = random_state)
    mean_diff = bootstrap_sample.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[1,0] - bootstrap_sample.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[0,0]
    mean_diffs.append(mean_diff)

    left = np.percentile(mean_diffs, alpha/2*100)*(-1)
    right = np.percentile(mean_diffs, 100-alpha/2*100)*(-1)
    mean = -(df.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[1,0] - df.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[0,0])
```

Next, I am creating a loop to run the bootstrap function for all my campaigns (this works).

```
for i in campaigns:     
    print(Lift for: {i}')     
    bootstrap_ci(df[df['campaign_name']==i],'conversion','group')
```

Then, I tried adding this code to the loop function to append the variables left, right, mean (this does not work):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([]) --initiate a new df

for i in campaigns:     
    print(Lift for: {i}')     
    bootstrap_ci(df[df['campaign_name']==i],'conversion','group')
    df = df.append(i, mean, left, right) --append the relevant variables to df
```

Please advise as the df returns nothing...

Comment: Is the single quote your error?

Comment: Are you returning `left`, `right`, and `mean` from your function?  If not, how is the caller supposed to access those values?

Comment: rename new df to `new_df` instead of `df`, your old df and new df should be named differently

Comment: Do you design to keep "campaign" column to be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append new items with `df.at[index, column] = value`, as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def bootstrap_ci(df, variable, classes, repetitions=1000, alpha=0.05, random_state=None):
    df = df[[variable, classes]]
    bootstrap_sample_size = len(df)
    mean_diffs = []
    
    for i in range(repetitions):
        bootstrap_sample = df.sample(n=bootstrap_sample_size, replace=True,
                                     random_state=random_state)
        mean_diff = bootstrap_sample.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[1, 0] - bootstrap_sample.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[0, 0]
        mean_diffs.append(mean_diff)
    
    left = np.percentile(mean_diffs, alpha / 2 * 100) * (-1)
    right = np.percentile(mean_diffs, 100 - alpha / 2 * 100) * (-1)
    mean = -(df.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[1, 0] - df.groupby(classes).mean().iloc[0, 0])
   
   # added return statement
   return dict(mean=mean, left=left, right=right)


# initiate a new df
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [], 'left': [], 'right': []})

for i in campaigns:     
    print('Lift for: {i}')     
    values = bootstrap_ci(df[df['campaign_name'] == i], 'conversion', 'group')
    
    # append the relevant variables to df
    for k, v in values.items():
        new_df.at[i, k] = v
```